# Extract vector from std::map<int, std::vector>

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, stl

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int>  VectorInt;
typedef std::map<int, VectorInt> MapVectorInt;

int main() { 
        MapVectorInt myMap;

        VectorInt v1;
        v1.push_back(1);
        v1.push_back(3);
        v1.push_back(5);

        VectorInt v2;
        v2.push_back(2);
        v2.push_back(4);
        v2.push_back(6);

        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(0, v1));
        myMap.insert(std::make_pair(1, v2)); 



        return 0;
}
```

What is the bese way to take (extract/get) the vector at position x (eg 1,2...);

Comment: have you tried anything? the fact your value element is a vector doesn't change the semantics of accessing a map

Comment: You should look at some guides how to use a map.

Comment: Same as you would extract any other type from a map. There isn't anything special about `std::vector`.

Comment: instead of downvoting please refer to my update question. This is issue does not seem that simple. Of course I have used "at".

Comment: re. the edit, the output is as I would expect: `myMap[0]` has six entries `1 3 5 2 4 6`, and `myMap[1]` is empty. Can you explain what you expected to happen?  Maybe you meant to push 2,4,6 into `v2` instead of `v1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the vector in the map with `myMap[0]` or `myMap[1]`.

You could make an alias for either of those, e.g. `auto& x = myMap[0];`. Using the alias will access the vector as it is stored in the map.

To take a copy of the vector  (so that you can modify the map contents without changing the copy), it is just the same as copying any other object:

```
auto x = myMap[0];
```

Note that `0` and `1` refer to the key you used in the `insert` call; not to the search order or the insertion order (although in your example those things all happen to be the same).

Comment: And check the size of map before doing that.

Comment: @Dkg size check is neither necessary nor useful. maps are indexed by a key. I assume OP meant 'key' when he said 'position'.

Comment: Can you please see my update question? It didn't work

Comment: @cateof never say "it didn't work" , instead say what you saw and explain how it differs to what you expected

Comment: OK, as I said I want to extract the vector at the current position. Not the map.

Comment: @cateof your comment makes no sense, maps do not have a "current position", and my code already is for extracting a vector.

Comment: @M.M Agree.. but size check is for making sure that you have keys available in the map, especially if you're taking keys from some arrays / files etc

Comment: @Dkg a size check would not ensure that any particular key is present

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
auto v1=myMap[0]; //This will do a deep copy for the vector
```

or:

```
auto& v1=myMap[0]; //This will hold a reference to the vector
```

Be careful in the second approach because if the item has removed , the reference will be invalid.

If you want a safe option use `std::map::at`:

```
auto v1=myMap.at(0);
```

or:

```
auto& v1=myMap.at(0)
```

This will throw an exception (`std::out_of_range`) if the item is not there.

Comment: @M.M Oh it seems that I get used to std::vector. Thanks

Comment: Can you please see my update question? It didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:
Best place to look for it http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

---

With context:

For visualisation only, I guess you should express you intention as you said in your question(get an element from the map and not "eventually" insert it as using [] for accessing a non-existing element creates it), so:

```
const auto& search = myMap.find(1);
if (search != example.end()) {
    for(auto value: search->second) {
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "Not found\n";
}
```

[Try It Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/780635223a9501aa)